# In gnome-terminal, can I assign more than one shortcut to the same function?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want two different shortcuts to do the same thing in `gnome-terminal`. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean "...can I add more than one shortcut..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible (at least not without patching gnome-terminal's source).